# Catching / blocking SIGINT during system call

Tags: python, unix, signals, interrupt, system-calls

I've written a web crawler that I'd like to be able to stop via the keyboard.  I don't want the program to die when I interrupt it; it needs to flush its data to disk first.  I also don't want to catch `KeyboardInterruptedException`, because the persistent data could be in an inconsistent state.

My current solution is to define a signal handler that catches `SIGINT` and sets a flag; each iteration of the main loop checks this flag before processing the next url.

However, I've found that if the system happens to be executing `socket.recv()` when I send the interrupt, I get this:

```
^C
Interrupted; stopping...  // indicates my interrupt handler ran
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler_test.py", line 154, in <module>
    main()
  ...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 397, in readline
    data = recv(1)
socket.error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

and the process exits completely.  Why does this happen?  Is there a way I can prevent the interrupt from affecting the system call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`socket.recv()` calls the underlying POSIX-compliant `recv` function in the C layer, which, in turn, will return an error code `EINTR` when the process receives a `SIGINT` while waiting for incoming data in `recv()`. This error code can be used on the C side (if you were programming in C) to detect that `recv()` returned not because there is more data available on the socket but because the process received a `SIGINT`. Anyway, this error code is turned into an exception by Python, and since it is never caught, it terminates your application with the traceback you see. The solution is simply to catch `socket.error`, check the error code and if it is equal to `errno.EINTR`, ignore the exception silently. Something like this:

```
import errno

try:
    # do something
    result = conn.recv(bufsize)
except socket.error as (code, msg):
    if code != errno.EINTR:
        raise
```

Comment: Using the magic number 4 in place of `EINTR` or whatever identifier Python provides for it is a very bad practice. It's likely to break on some archs.

Comment: Sure, you are right. I read the Python library docs once again and it seems that the `errno` module provides these constants so I'll adjust the example.

Comment: Just a note: this is deprecated in python 3.3, according to PEP-3151. 

Instead should be used OSError builtin.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want your socket call to be interrupted disable the interrupt behavior after you set the signal handler.

```
signal.signal(<your signal here>, <your signal handler function here>)
signal.siginterrupt(<your signal here>, False)
```

In the signal handling function set some flag, e.g. a threading.Event() and then check that flag in your main processing function and terminate your crawler gracefully.

Background info here:

- [linux signal man
  page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) See discussion about SA_RESTART flag.
- [python
  docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.siginterrupt)