# Python process kill with signal and "[Errno 4] Interrupted system call"

Tags: python, signals, blocking, epoll

I have big python (2.7) application and SIGUSR2-handler for program debugging – I want to have an opportunity to interrupt app anytime and explore it state. Well it works fine almost always but it does not work if the application hangs on some I/O operation, for example on receiving data from network or receiving the job from queue (I use rabbitmq). In these cases the app breaks with "[Errno 4] Interrupted system call" error. Can I fix this? Thanks.

P.S.: Solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016868/2703236 does not work for me because I have thousands of network usages in the app and it's impossible to handle EINTR of them all.